# How to know the limitations of specific VxWorks version?

Tags: embedded, vxworks, rtos, manual

I was trying to download VxWorks 5.x (specifically 5.11) manual, to understand the limitations with respect to the number of tasks, message queues, stack sizes , memory restrictions and semaphores. 
Can any one of you please post any link to download or share the above-mentioned limitations?

Comment: "... and semaphores"; what could that mean?  With VxWorks, the practical limits are entirely down to the hardware platform, not the OS. Otherwise, theoretical limits are determined by the data type of API arguments.  You say you tried to download the manual; did you not succeed?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could not able to find the link for specific version 5.1. I can find only programmer's guide.

Answer (score 1):

There are not, as far as I am aware, any inherent limits in the number of tasks, message queues, stack sizes, sempahores etc.

While there clearly will be an upper bound, this is primarily dictated by the hardware platform, in particular the amount of memory.

This is especially true of message queues, and the stack size for various tasks.

If you are after particular documentation, you should contact your WindRiver support rep - documentation is freely available to all licensed users